# Python loop not adding to list, therefore not providing an output

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I am making a piece of code that generates bingo cards. It makes sure that there are going to be 5 numbers on each horizontal row and that each vertical column has the numbers between 1-9, 10-19, 20-29, 30-39, 40-49, 50-59, 60-69, 70-79, and 80-90. However the list `values` never has anything appended to it, so it can never get to the next loop. Here is the code:

```
def generate_nums(nums):             #nums looks like this: [[],[],[]] - which is how it is inputed
    for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        while True:
            values = []
            Min = 1
            Max = 9
            counter = 0
            for j in range(0, len(nums[i])):
                value = random.randint(0, 1)
                values.append(value)
                if value == 1:
                    counter += 1
            if counter == 5:
                for item in values:
                    if item == 1:
                        nums[i].append(random.randint(Min, Max))
                    else:
                        nums[i].append(" ")
                    if Min == 1:
                        Min = 10
                    else:
                        Min += 10
                    if Max == 79:
                        Max = 90
                    else:
                        Max += 10
                break

#Function call
if __name__ == "__main__":
    nums = [[],[],[]]
    print(generate_nums(nums))
```

Any help is appreciated, I am only looking to improve my knowledge as I am doing computer science GCSE and I love python and the challenges it presents, though I don't know what to do here.
Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question with the exact way you call this function. If you supply empty lists then the body of `for j in range(...` will never execute.

Comment: I wonder if this is an indentation problem, starting from the ``if counter == 5`` line.

Comment: Edited to show function call

Comment: Yes, so each `len(nums[i])` is zero, so nothing inside your `while` loop really executes.

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html to avoid unpythonic `for index in len( ...` constructs

Comment: I edited it so now it is ```for j in range(0, 5)``` and got this output: ```[[5, 10, 21, 38, 44], [], []]```